# Excepción no controlada en DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

Tengo un pequeño problema a la hora de multiplicar dos matrices en C# de WindowsForm.

Tengo que realizar la multiplicación de dos matrices, pero a la hora de querer generar la tercer matriz, me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

P.D 
Agrego el código que llevo de momento, por si agiliza el apoyo.

Lo que realizo en el siguient código es declarar las dimensiones de las dos matrices desde los elementos *numericUpDown*, posterior a ello comienzo la operación de ambas matrices.

```
columna1 = (int)numericUpDown3.Value;
            fila1 = (int)numericUpDown4.Value;
            columna2 = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            fila2 = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;

            dataGridView2.ColumnCount = columna1;
            dataGridView2.RowCount = fila1;

            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = columna2;
            dataGridView1.RowCount = fila2;

            matriz1 = new int[columna1, fila1];
            for(int a = 0; a < columna1; ++a)
            {
                dataGridView2.Columns[a].Name = Convert.ToString(a + 1);
                for(int b = 0; b < fila1; ++b)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows[b].HeaderCell.Value = Convert.ToString(b + 1);
                }
            }

            matriz2 = new int[columna2, fila2];
            for (int a = 0; a < columna2; ++a)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[a].Name = Convert.ToString(a + 1);
                for (int b = 0; b < fila2; ++b)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[b].HeaderCell.Value = Convert.ToString(b + 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Cuando presiono al boton "Multiplicar" me arroja el error anterior.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es asignar un valor al datagrid en la posicion de los contadores de los ciclos deberia ser algo como esto `dataGridView3.Rows[a].Cells[b]`

Comment: Estás realizando DataGridView3[a,b], si entiendo bien el datagridview3 es el grid inferior y ese no tiene filas, por  lo que cualquier acceso será incorrecto. Posibles soluciones: pregenerar las filas/columnas antes de operar con los datos, o irlos generando mientras se opera.

Comment: @LuisFernando, En qué parte va la declaración? Me imagino que entre los ciclos, no? Intentare ponerlos previamente.

Comment: Exactamente donde esta la "X" en la foto que posteaste. Toma en cuenta lo que dice @james_bond

Answer (score 0):

Estás realizando DataGridView3[a,b], si entiendo bien el datagridview3 es el grid inferior y ese no tiene filas, por lo que cualquier acceso será incorrecto. Posibles soluciones: pregenerar las filas/columnas antes de operar con los datos, o irlos generando mientras se opera.

El primer caso es más fácil, solo tenes que hacer:

```
datagridview3.ColumnCount = 3; //o el valor adecuado según tus variables
datagridview3.RowCount = 4; //o el valor adecuado según tus variables
```

La documentación del [RowCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount(v=vs.110).aspx) y [ColumnCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columncount(v=vs.110).aspx) describen el comportamiento de estas propiedades.

Te agrego lo que dice la documentación para RowCount (que también es válido para ColumCount -salvo que en este caso se aplica a la colección de columnas)

> Si RowCount se establece en un valor menor que el valor actual, las
>   filas se quitarán del final de la Rows colección. Si RowCount se
>   establece en un valor mayor que el valor actual, se agregarán filas al
>   final de la Rows colección. Las filas adicionales se basan en la fila
>   especificada en el RowTemplate propiedad. Si establece la RowCount
>   propiedad en 0, se quitan todas las filas de la DataGridView. Esto
>   equivale a llamar a la DataGridViewRowCollection.Clear (método).

Comment: Gracias por la documentación le echaré una leída. He intentado agregar las lineas de arriba a sus respectivos ciclos. Sin embargo me arroja un argumento de rango fuera de excepción donde; 'El valor de 0' no es un valor valido para 'RowCount'

Comment: No debe ser cero, debe ser el valor de las dimensiones de la matriz producto tanto para filas y columnas.